# Как правильно работать с документацией? (библиотек и самого языка)

Tags: python, документация

Вызубрил теорию. Началась практика.

Обнаружилось, что документация к некоторым модулям и библиотекам неимоверно большая. К примеру рассмотрим python, tkinter. Если через help открыть модуль, то инструкция будет выдана в не вполне читабельном виде.

Как можно ускорить процесс поиска нужных методов, классов и т.п. в документах, чтобы не перерывать весь документ каждый раз строчка за строчкой? (тетрадка-ручка, волшебные сайты?)

Comment: @Pogremix Модули и библиотеки расположены в репозиториях в  открытом доступе. Там и можно с разработчиками и авторами пообщаться

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

help фукнция использует инструмент под названием PyDoc. PyDoc умеет генерировать HTML отчеты, которые гораздо удобнее и могут быть тем что нужно. Например, в 3.5 при выполнении команды  `python -m pydoc -b` в командной строке, запускается сервер и открывается браузер в котором собственно можно увидеть всю доступную документацию в удобном виде.

Дополнительно об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)